# Is there a way to return the field_weights values?

Tags: sphinx

When I run a `SphinxQL` query I can request the `Weight()`

```
Select ID,Weight(),Title from Index_A where MATCH('@(Title,Description) London')
```

Which returns the weight that Sphinx assigned each match however when I add `field_weights` to the query:

```
Select ID,Weight(),Title from Index_A where MATCH('@(Title,Description) London') OPTION field_weights=(Title=1000)
```

I can't request a column to show the field_weights. I've tried `Select field_weights()` and `Select field_weights(Title)` to no avail and I'm trying to get an idea of how this is actually being scored.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure, but **if** it's available, it will be via the `PACKEDFACTORS()` function

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/misc-functions.html

Comment: @BarryHuinter Actually as I found out `Weight()` will always return the current weighting. So if I modify a Select to include `field_weights=` then `Select Weights()` will return different values then w/o. So that is basically `Select field_weights`